# Velvet effect for background in Adobe Illustrator

Tags: adobe-illustrator, background

Does anybody know/have ideas how to make velvet effect background in Adobe Illustrator 5.x?

An example I'm talking about:

[image]

Comment: Do you have an example of what velvet you are talking about?

Comment: Apologize forgot adding it

Comment: Why Illustrator? This would be a challenge for anyone. You're better off using Photoshop to create the texture and them placing it in Illustrator as a raster image.

Comment: you can do it but it'd be a lot of work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**This is something you would *use* in Illustrator not *make*.** It appears to be a scan of a painted surface or multiple painted surfaces composited.

Photoshop is the app you're looking for. When you're ready to apply it to your Illustrator artwork, just `Place` the image as a linked graphic.

Comment: Decorative wall painting is actually something I did for money as support staff many many years ago. The snapshot looks like a dark base color, a light spatter coat (think a really wet brush waved in the air or a paint-filled toothbrush where you flick the bristles with your thumbnail), and a 3rd middle tone roughly applied with a brush and then wiped with a rag. All three of these things can be simulated with layers and the brush settings in photoshop.